# Using strcat to append spaces. Compiles but overwrites string

Tags: c, double-quotes, strcpy, quotations

The language I am working in is C.

I am trying to use a mix of built in c string functions in order to take a list of tokens (space separated) and "convert" it into a list of tokens that is split by quotations.

A string like

> echo "Hello 1 2 3 4" test test2

gets converted to

> [echo] ["Hello] [1] [2] [3] [4"] [test] [test2]

I then use my code (at bottom) to ***attempt*** to convert it into something like

> [echo] [Hello 1 2 3 4] [test] [test2]

For some reason the second 'token' in the quoted statement gets overridden.
Here's a snippet of the code that runs over the token list and converts it to the new one.

```
 88                 for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
 89                         if ( (strstr(tokenized[i],"\"") != NULL) && (inQuotes == 0)) {
 90                                 inQuotes = 1;
 91                                 tokenizedQuoted[quoteCounter] = tokenized[i];
 92                                 strcat(tokenizedQuoted[quoteCounter]," ");
 93                         } else if ( (strstr(tokenized[i],"\"") != NULL) && (inQuotes == 1)) {
 94                                 inQuotes = 0;
 95                                 strcat(tokenizedQuoted[quoteCounter],tokenized[i]);
 96                                 quoteCounter++;
 97                         } else {
 98                                 if (inQuotes == 0) {
 99                                         tokenizedQuoted[quoteCounter] = tokenized[i];
100                                         quoteCounter++;
101                                 } else if (inQuotes == 1) {
102                                         strcat(tokenizedQuoted[quoteCounter], tokenized[i]);
103                                         strcat(tokenizedQuoted[quoteCounter], " ");
104                                 }
105                         }
106
107                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, adding an space to a `char *` means that the memory pointed by it needs more bytes. Since you do not provide it, you are overwritting the first byte of the following "word" with `\0`, so the `char *` to it is interpreted as the empty string. Note that writting to a location that has not been reserved is an undefined behavior, so really **ANYTHING** could happen (from segmentation fault to "correct" results with no errors).

Use `malloc` to create a new buffer for the expanded result with enough bytes for it (do not forget to `free` the old buffers if they were `malloc`'d).

Comment: Is there any way to do this if I never malloc'd the array at the start? My 2 arrays are char* tokenized[maxArgs] and tokenizedQuoted[maxArgs]

Comment: The original storage of the strings is not relevant (other than for avoiding a memory leak). You need to enlarge an string? Reserve enough space for the new string and perform your operation in that space. If you used `strtok`, you only need to free the original position. It is hard to give more advice without seeing the code that fills these arrays.